# How does a global variable behave when using Python joblib parallel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, joblib

How do global variables behave in context of being accessed and modified by the function I parallelized using joblib's `Parallel` functionality.

Suppose this is the code I've written

```
    # Global variable 
    client = CustomClass()
    
    # Thread level function
    def runThread():
       # modify client variables
       # call client methods etc
    
    # Call the runThread() function using joblib Parallel, 5 threads
    Parallel(n_jobs=5, backend="multiprocessing")(delayed(runThread) for _ in range(5))
```

So how does the global client object I've created behave as, does it:

1. Each instance of the `runThread()` function will have access to it's own copy of the global variable and the different parallel instances can independently modify/access the client, OR
2. All the processes that we spawn will share the same instance of the `client` and the different processes access and modify the global `client` and I need to control access with a mutex ?

Comment: Check out: [Shared-memory semantics](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parallel.html#shared-memory-semantics)

Comment: you aren't using multithreading or threads in your code, btw. Multiple processes *do not share state*. It is as if you run multiple scripts from the command line, although, this takes care of IPC.

Comment: Thanks @JonSG, above doc makes it clear that each process will have it's own instance of the client